# how to solve failed login on node.js and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, postman

I'm creating a login and register using nodejs and mysql
when I tried it at Postman, when I registered it was successful, but when I tried to login, on the postman page it was always "sending request" and no error on code

This is the error and the code
[sending request postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaEEv.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9ZFU.png)

here the code Users.js

```
    const express = require("express")
const users = express.Router()
const cors = require('cors')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const User = require('../models/User')

users.use(cors())

process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

users.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
    const today = new Date()
    const userData = {
        Nama: req.body.Nama,
        Nama_toko:req.body.Nama_toko,
        Email: req.body.Email,
        Password: req.body.Password,
        create:today
    }
    User.findOne({
        where:{
            Email: req.body.Email
        }
    })
    .then(user =>{
        if(!user){
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.Password,10,(err,hash)=>{
                userData.Password= hash
                User.create(userData)
                .then(user =>{
                    res.json({status: user.Email + ' registered'})
                })
                .catch(err =>{
                    res.send('error: '+err)
                })
            })
        }else{
            res.json({error: "User Alredy Exits"})
        }
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})

users.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            Email: req.body.Email
        }
    })
    .then(user => {
        if(user){
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.Password, user.Password)){
                let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY,{
                    expiresIn: 1440
                })
                res.send(token)
        }
    }else{
            res.status(400).json({error: "User doesnt not exist"})
         }
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        res.status(400).json({error: "Error salah"})
    })
})

module.exports =  users
```

server.js

```
var express = require("express")
var cors = require("cors")
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var app = express()
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

var Users = require('./routes/Users')
app.use('/Users', Users)

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("Server is running at : " + port)
})
```

Comment: I don't see an error. To me it looks like it's just waiting for a response... and i don't see any cases in your code at first glance that would result in a non-repsonse

Comment: but it tooks a long time, i have been waiting for 30 minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request isn't responded, it usually means that you haven't called `res.send()` or `res.json()` on your routes.

```js
    if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.Password, user.Password)){
        let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY,{
            expiresIn: 1440
        })
        res.send(token)
    }
```

You don't have `else` block in this `if`, it's possible that the `bcrypt.compareSync` returns false and the response isn't being handled, try:

```js
    if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.Password, user.Password)){
        let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY,{
            expiresIn: 1440
        })
        res.send(token)
    } else {
        res.status(401).json({error: "Incorrect Password"})
    }
```

and see if you get any response.